# Изменение макета HTML пс помощью PHP

Tags: php, html

Всем добра!

Есть анкета на bootstrap, которая на сервер AJAX'ом отправляет всё своё содержимое,
Это содержимое, нужно рассовать по местам в файле, назовем его "anketa.html". Файл этот просто лежит на сервере, и открывается только для изменения, и последующего превращения его в pdf, всем известными методами.

Так вот вопрос, как рассовать содержимое?

Кусок кода ankete.html

```html
    <div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;border: 1px solid;border-top: none;">
                <div style="width:25%;display: inline-block;border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.1. Given names / Имена</label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:74%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="given-names"></label>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div style=" display: inline-block; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; border-top: none;">
                <div style="width:25%; display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.2. Surname / Фамилия</label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:74%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="surname"></label>
                    </div>          
            </div>
            <div style=" display: inline-block; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; border-top: none;">
                <div style=" width:25%; display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.3. Date of birth / Дата рождения</label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:74%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="date-of-birth"></label>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div style=" display: inline-block; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; border-top: none;">
                <div style=" width:25%; display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.4. Place of birth / Место рождения</label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:74%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="place-of-birth"></label>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; border-top: none;">
                <div style=" width:25%; display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.5. Citizenship / Гражданство </label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:74%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="citizenship"></label>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div style=" display: inline-block; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; border-top: none;">
                <div style=" width:25%; display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.6. Sex / Пол</label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:74%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="sex"></label>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div style=" display: inline-block; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; border-top: none;">
                <div style=" width:25%; display: inline-block;border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.7. Passport No. / Номер паспорта </label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:74%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="passport-num"></label>
                </div>          
            </div>
            <div style=" display: inline-block; width: 100%; border: 1px solid; border-top: none;">
                <div style=" width:25%; display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.8. Date of issue / Дата выдачи</label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:24%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="date-of-issue"></label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:25%; display: inline-block; border-right: 1px solid; border-left: 1px solid;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px">1.9. Date of expiry / Дата окончания срока</label>
                </div>
                <div style=" width:24%; display: inline-block;">
                    <label style="margin-left:10px" id="date-of-expiry"></label>
                </div>          
            </div>
        </div>
```

Кусок получаемых AJAX'ом данных

```php
    Array
(
    [given-names] => 
    [surname] => 
    [date-of-birth] => 10/22/2019
    [place-of-birth] => 
    [citizenship] => RU
    [passport-num] => 
    [issue-date] => 10/22/2019
    [expiry-date] => 10/22/2019
)
```

Если что данные стоковые

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

1) Надо сохранить html-файл как ankete.php;

2) В начало `<body>` вставить `<? ваш php-скрипт обработчик AJAX-запроса ?>`;

3) AJAX-запрос должен вызывать ankete.php (либо ankete.php надо вызвать и передать в него данные любым способом: через другой скрипт/из базы, и.т.д.);

4) Прописать php-вставки значений в html, используя конструкцию `<?= ?>`, аналог echo.

```
<label style="margin-left:10px"><?=$_POST['given-names']?></label>
```

На выходе будет html-страница с полученными из запроса значениям, без php-кода.